# Authenticating a Today Widget for API access

Tags: ios, today-extension, ios-extensions

I need to add a Today Widget/extension to an existing iOS app, which requires the user to sign in via a `WKWebView`.

As the extension only communicates with Apple frameworks or via `openURL()` back to the main app, how would I best share the authentication token stored in the main app with the Today Widget/extension, so that it can make authenticated API calls?

Can this be done with a shared keychain? Or is there another secure alternative?

It is not feasible to have the user sign in again in the Today extension UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use App Groups to share data between the main application and today widget extension. You need to activate App Group for your application and create:

```
UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.com.yourOrganization.yourApplicationName")
```

In the main application set your data in this UserDefaults and try to access it from within your Today Widget extension.

Comment: Thank you. Is this secure and therefore suitable for sharing authentication tokens?

Comment: Well UserDefaults is not the place to keep secured data definitely, you can consider encrypting the token in some way if this is an issue for you. However single token should not be a security issue in my opinion.

Comment: I've just discovered it is possible to use a shared keychain group - see 14m00 in this WWDC video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/217/

Comment: Yes, you are right, this might be the solution for your issue. You can write answer for your question, so others can see your conclusion.

Comment: Done! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Shared Keychain Group to store the token, as described at 14m00s in [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/217).